# A single Junit test is running twice in Maven build

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running junit tests on a project with mvn clean test command in Jenkins

Strangely only of the tests of a particular test class is running twice.

Other tests are only running once.

maven surefire configuration in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

i am totally clueless

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Can you show your build output with debug enabled? How is your JUnit test class implemented?

Comment: More info please ... annotation in test class ?  use of suite test ? use of cobertura-maven-plugin or something equivalent ? ...

Comment: Had a similar case recently with turned out to be double dependencys on the test package, thats what i would check first in this case.

Comment: Are you using test suites ?

Comment: thanks all for the replies...annonation @test is used in the class..i am not using any test suite..just all the tests under the project is being run

Comment: also it seems only the failed tests are run twice...i have not set any rule or configuration to run failed test twice

Comment: Please add a log output and a pom file ...

Comment: Are you sure that are really run twice? Maybe JUnit publisher show them twice? I had the same case some time ago.